# Microsoft Paint not filling in every pixel

Tags: microsoft-paint

Suppose I have an image, and this image is a blue ball on a yellow background. Thus, the image consists of two colors to the human eye: Blue and Yellow.

However, near the borders of the ball are varying shades of blue inside the ball, and varying shades of yellow outside of the ball.

I would like to make these pixels the same color "Red". They are almost the same yellow, but the fill function can't tell the difference.

How do I make these pixels the same color without having to fill them in, one by one?

Comment: idk Paint at all, but generally you would either have to make a selection & feather the edges, or change the tolerance level/sensitivity for a paint bucket fill.

Comment: @Jossie you can't do that in Paint. Its paint bucket tool is relatively unsophisticated and only pours colour into pixels that are absolutely identical (as well as contiguous) to the pixel you click on. What you're doing requires a more advanced image-editing program, such as Photoshop. Photoshop allows you to adjust the tolerance of its fill tool, which allows you to include similar pixels.

Comment: @MrEthernet - thanks for confirmation. I wasn't sure about Paint, I'm not on Windows so can't test & am very much used to Photoshop for this type of task.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't possible in Microsoft Paint.

The paint bucket tool in Paint is unsophisticated and only pours colour into contiguous pixels that are *absolutely identical* in colour to the pixel where the tool is clicked.

What you're attempting to do requires a more advanced image-editing program, such as Photoshop. Photoshop allows you to adjust the tolerance of its fill tool with values ranging from 0 to 255.

- **Tolerance = 0** makes the tool highly specific, so the tool only affects pixels which are absolutely identical in colour.
- **Tolerance = 255** selects pixels of all colours (i.e. the entire image).

The behaviour of the paint bucket tool in Microsoft Paint is the equivalent of Photoshop's paint bucket tool when set to 0.

Unfortunately, as Paint does not allow you to increase its tolerance from 0, you are stuck with it in a highly specific mode which struggles with images that contain even extremely subtle colour gradients.

Comment: I just downloaded Photoshop Express but I don't see the paint bucket tool.

Comment: Photoshop Express (not to be confused with Photoshop *Elements*, which is actually much better) is a free app with about 1% of the functionality of the full Photoshop application. I just installed it to see what it can do because I'd never heard of it before. Unfortunately, it's pretty much useless for anything but the simplest of tasks and doesn't even have the paint bucket tool. You can install the full version of Photoshop for free and use the 7-day trial.